# generic non-invasive cache wrapper

Tags: c++, generics, templates, metaprogramming, memoization

I'm trying create a class which adds functionality to a generic class, without directly interfacing with the wrapped class.  A good example of this would be a smart pointer.  Specifically, I'd like to create a wrapper which caches all the i/o for one (or any?) method invoked through the wrapper.  Ideally, the cache wrapper have the following properties:

- it would not require the wrapping class to be changed in any way (i.e. generic)
- it would not require the wrapped class to be changed in any way (i.e. generic)
- it would not change the interface or syntax for using the object significantly

For example, it would be really nice to use it like this:

```
CacheWrapper<NumberCruncher> crunchy;
...
// do some long and ugly calculation, caching method input/output
result = crunchy->calculate(input); 
...
// no calculation, use cached result
result = crunchy->calculate(input);
```

although something goofy like this would be ok:

```
result = crunchy.dispatch (&NumberCruncher::calculate, input);
```

I feel like this should be possible in C++, although possibly with some syntactic gymnastics somewhere along the line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have the answer you are seeking, or, at least, I almost do. It uses the dispatch style you suggested was goofy, but I think it meets the first two criteria you set forth, and more or less meets the third.

1. The wrapping class does not have to be modified at all.
2. It doesn't modify the wrapped class at all.
3. It only changes the syntax by introducing a dispatch function.

The basic idea is to create a template class, whose parameter is the class of the object to be wrapped, with a template `dispatch` method, whose parameters are the argument and return types of a member function. The dispatch method looks up the passed in member function pointer to see if it has been called before. If so, it retrieves the record of previous method arguments and calculated results to return the previously calculated value for the argument given to dispatch, or to calculate it if it is new.

Since what this wrapping class does is also called [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), I've elected to call the template `Memo` because that is shorter to type than `CacheWrapper` and I'm starting to prefer shorter names in my old age.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

// An anonymous namespace to hold a search predicate definition. Users of
// Memo don't need to know this implementation detail, so I keep it
// anonymous. I use a predicate to search a vector of pairs instead of a
// simple map because a map requires that operator< be defined for its key
// type, and operator< isn't defined for member function pointers, but
// operator== is.
namespace {
    template <typename Type1, typename Type2>
    class FirstEq {
        FirstType value;

    public:
        typedef std::pair<Type1, Type2> ArgType;

        FirstEq(Type1 t) : value(t) {}

        bool operator()(const ArgType& rhs) const { 
            return value == rhs.first;
        }
    };
};

template <typename T>
class Memo {
    // Typedef for a member function of T. The C++ standard allows casting a
    // member function of a class with one signature to a type of another
    // member function of the class with a possibly different signature. You
    // aren't guaranteed to be able to call the member function after
    // casting, but you can use the pointer for comparisons, which is all we
    // need to do.
    typedef void (T::*TMemFun)(void);

    typedef std::vector< std::pair<TMemFun, void*> > FuncRecords;

    T           memoized;
    FuncRecords funcCalls;

public:
    Memo(T t) : memoized(t) {}

    template <typename ReturnType, typename ArgType>
    ReturnType dispatch(ReturnType (T::* memFun)(ArgType), ArgType arg) {

        typedef std::map<ArgType, ReturnType> Record;

        // Look up memFun in the record of previously invoked member
        // functions. If this is the first invocation, create a new record.
        typename FuncRecords::iterator recIter = 
            find_if(funcCalls.begin(),
                    funcCalls.end(),
                    FirstEq<TMemFun, void*>(
                        reinterpret_cast<TMemFun>(memFun)));

        if (recIter == funcCalls.end()) {
            funcCalls.push_back(
                std::make_pair(reinterpret_cast<TMemFun>(memFun),
                               static_cast<void*>(new Record)));
            recIter = --funcCalls.end();
        }

        // Get the record of previous arguments and return values.
        // Find the previously calculated value, or calculate it if
        // necessary.
        Record*                   rec      = static_cast<Record*>(
                                                 recIter->second);
        typename Record::iterator callIter = rec->lower_bound(arg);

        if (callIter == rec->end() || callIter->first != arg) {
            callIter = rec->insert(callIter,
                                   std::make_pair(arg,
                                                  (memoized.*memFun)(arg)));
        }
        return callIter->second;
    }
};
```

Here is a simple test showing its use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Memo.h"

using namespace std;

struct C {
    int three(int x) { 
        cout << "Called three(" << x << ")" << endl;
        return 3;
    }

    double square(float x) {
        cout << "Called square(" << x << ")" << endl;
        return x * x;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    C       c;
    Memo<C> m(c);

    cout << m.dispatch(&C::three, 1) << endl;
    cout << m.dispatch(&C::three, 2) << endl;
    cout << m.dispatch(&C::three, 1) << endl;
    cout << m.dispatch(&C::three, 2) << endl;

    cout << m.dispatch(&C::square, 2.3f) << endl;
    cout << m.dispatch(&C::square, 2.3f) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which produces the following output on my system (MacOS 10.4.11 using g++ 4.0.1):

```
Called three(1)
3
Called three(2)
3
3
3
Called square(2.3)
5.29
5.29
```

---

### NOTES

- This only works for methods which take 1 argument and return a result. It doesn't work for methods which take 0 arguments, or 2, or 3, or more arguments. This shouldn't be a big problem, though. You can implement overloaded versions of dispatch which take different numbers of arguments up to some reasonable max. This is what the [Boost Tuple library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) does. They implement tuples of up to 10 elements and assume most programmers don't need more than that.
- The possibility of implementing multiple overloads for dispatch is why I used the FirstEq predicate template with the find_if algorithm instead of a simple for loop search. It is a little more code for a single use, but if you are going to do a similar search multiple times, it ends up being less code overall and less chance to get one of the loops subtlely wrong.
- It doesn't work for methods returning nothing, i.e. `void`, but if the method doesn't return anything, then you don't need to cache the result!
- It doesn't work for template member functions of the wrapped class because you need to pass an actual member function pointer to dispatch, and an un-instantiated template function doesn't have a pointer (yet). There may be a way around this, but I haven't tried much yet.
- I haven't done much testing of this yet, so it may have some subtle (or not-so-subtle) problems.
- I don't think a completely seamless solution which satisfies all your requirements with no change in syntax at all is possible in C++. (though I'd love to be proven wrong!) Hopefully this is close enough.
- When I researched this answer, I got a lot of help from [this very extensive write up](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx) on implementing member function delegates in C++. Anyone who wants to learn way more than they realized was possible to know about member function pointers should give that article a good read.

Comment: The problem I can think of, of course, is if the wrapped instance is modified by the call of the function. From the code it seems that the memoization is crude: ie does not take into account changes of the object or changes in the argument list... kudos though.

Comment: @Matthieu I'll have to agree with your first point. Changes to object state will not be reflected in subsequent calls. Although, I think that would be a problem with any approach to auto-memoization. On your second point (changes to argument list) I'm not sure what you mean. If you meant changes in arity of the function, that is true, but see my first bullet point in the NOTES section of the answer. If you meant that it doesn't account for changes in arg value, then I think you missed the call to rec->lower_bound(arg). Thanks for your critique though! Maybe I should clarify my code a little...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be easily done using just a wrapper as you'll have to intercept the IO calls, so wrapping a class would put the code at the wrong layer. In essence, you want to substitute the IO code underneath the object, but you're trying to do it from the top layer. If you're thinking of the code as an onion, you're trying to modify the outer skin in order to affect something two or three layers in; IMHO that suggests the design might need a rethink.

If the class that you're trying to wrap/modify this way does allow you to pass in the stream (or whatever IO mechanism you use), then substituting that one for a caching one would be the right thing to do; in essence that would be what you'd be trying to achieve with your wrapper as well.

Comment: i think I/O he meant was a method input output values.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a simple task, assuming the "NumberCruncher" has a known interface, let's say int operator(int).
Note that you'll need to make it more complicated to support other interfaces. In order to do so, i'm adding another template parameter, an Adaptor. Adaptor should convert some interface to a known interface. Here's simple and dumb implementation with static method, which is one way to do it. Also look what Functor is.

```
struct Adaptor1 {
     static int invoke(Cached1 & c, int input)  {
         return(c.foo1(input));
     }
};

struct Adaptor2 {
     static int invoke(Cached2 & c, int input)  {
         return(c.foo2(input));
     }
};

template class CacheWrapper<typename T, typeneame Adaptor>
{
private:
  T m_cachedObj;
  std::map<int, int> m_cache;

public:
   // add c'tor here

   int calculate(int input) {
      std::map<int, int>::const_iterator it = m_cache.find(input);
      if (it != m_cache.end()) {
         return(it->second);
      }
      int res = Adaptor::invoke(m_cachedObj, input);
      m_cache[input] = res;
      return(res);
   }
};
```

Comment: This solution isn't generic.  It ties the implementation of the data generator to the CasheWrapper.  I need some way of accessing the methods without specifying them specifically in the class body.

Comment: I added an Adptor, as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) / [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) (design patterns). You can use templates if you don't need the dynamic part of those patterns. The point is that you need to well define the interface that you will need.

Comment: Is that a generic solution?  That looks like it requires writing a separate class wrapper for all classes.

Comment: It is generic for a given interface. Like the template solution given by Drakosha. The template version is better if you do not want to make your existing classes inherit from that interface. But you lose the dynamic part of the patterns ...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out the case for handling object methods, but I think I've got a good fix for regular functions

```
template <typename input_t, typename output_t>
class CacheWrapper
{
public:
  CacheWrapper (boost::function<output_t (input_t)> f)
    : _func(f)
  {}

  output_t operator() (const input_t& in)
  {
    if (in != input_)
      {
        input_ = in;
        output_ = _func(in);
      }
    return output_;
  }

private:
  boost::function<output_t (input_t)> _func;
  input_t input_;
  output_t output_;
};
```

Which would be used as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CacheWrapper.h"

double squareit(double x) 
{ 
  std::cout << "computing" << std::endl;
  return x*x;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  CacheWrapper<double,double> cached_squareit(squareit);

  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
      std::cout << cached_squareit (10) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Any tips on how to get this to work for objects?

Comment: Possibly a second template class with template params `<typename input_t, typename class_t, typename output_t>` and constructor `CacheWrapper(boost::function<output_t (class_t*, input_t)> f)` ?

Comment: You CacheWrapper only saves the most recently used input. This won't be particularly useful unless you know your are going to get the same input multiple times in a row. It would be better to use a map<input_t, output_t> to save all previous calculations. Of course that may end up taking a lot of memory if you have many different values, so you may need logic to limit the size of your cache. Perhaps map wouldn't be the best data structure for a LRU cache, but the point is, you should save more than one previous calculation.

Comment: @A levy.  The question isn't about caching, it's about implementing a generic wrapper.  I used a trivial cache since it's trivial to implement and post as an example.